# I made a game in XNA - how can I share it with my friends?

Tags: xna

I've just finished programming a charming (albeit bare-bones) XNA version of arcade classic [Tempest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_%28arcade_game%29).

Hooray!

Given that this was a homework assignment, I'd like to be able to share it with my professor and my friends/classmates to solicit feedback.

(And let's be honest - if I have a question about how to add in an additional feature, it might be nice to be able to share it with folks on this site as well.)

Is there a better way of sharing an XNA game than by shuttling the visual studio - produced  executable around? Some way to host it on a website would be ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ClickOnce is pretty much perfect for hosting it on a website, you'll get auto-update and dependencies installer for free. There's a few gotchas but, it seems to work ok to me.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464156.aspx)

Comment: I'm on the PC, so this works wonderfully.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those will work for Xbox 360 version of it, you have to upload it to creators club to share it or distribute the built XNA package.

Answer (score 2):

You could upload the executable to [google docs](http://docs.google.com) and share it with them from there, depending on the size.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use ClickOnce as mentioned by Oskar - It works a treat. For really simple hosting and small scale distribution, I would get dropbox and drop it into your public folder and bit.ly it. then all you need to do is pass the shortened bit.ly link around to your friends/teacher etc.